# Add youtube playlist in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube

I'm using the npm package react-youtube to add videos in my react application but I also want to add youtube playlists in order to show all the videos in the playlist.

react-youtube works with videoId. I tried to put the playlist ID but it didn't work.

```
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';

const configVideo = {
        height: '120',
        width: '220',
        playerVars: {
          // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
          autoplay: 0,
        },
    }

<div className='programs-row'>
    <YouTube videoId="PLt2Yy5r4odxHh8fuxSHMHLDFamcR090Q2" opts={configVideo} />
</div>
```